# Одновременная запись и вывод, записываемого звука

Tags: java, android

У меня возникла задача сделать программу, которая одновременно записывает звук через микрофон и выводит его через динамик.

Даже если задержка между выводом и вводом будет размером в 1 секунду - это уже будет успех.

То есть задача заключается в одновременном использовании `MediaRecorder` и `MediaViewer` для одного файла, но можно ли так делать? Если можно, то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вам стоит обратить внимание на это :

https://github.com/google/oboe/tree/master/samples/LiveEffect

Comment: Наверное это и есть решение, но сколько я не пытался использовать это в своем проекте - у меня ничего так и не вышло.