# Использование кода с больших проектов с github`а в своем - Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: java, android, project-management

*Сразу скажу: программировать я начал недавно.*

### Как появился вопрос

Все началосm с того, что у меня возникла необходимость сделать приложение, которое одновременно записывает звук и выводит его же. Я задал [соответствующий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1206760/%d0%9e%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0/1206810#1206810) и мне дали [ссылку на проект с github`a](https://github.com/google/oboe/tree/master/samples/LiveEffect). Сначала мне показалось все простым - скопировать и вставить код, но все оказалось не так просто. Там было использовано много кода из других проектов и даже написанного на С++ (Весь этот код [находиться там же](https://github.com/google/oboe)).

### Что я пробовал

Я пытался разобраться как это все использовать, лазил по файлах (в основном grandle) из этого проекта, но это не помогло - я так и не понял как это использовать в моем приложении. Да что там использовать, я даже был бы рад, если просто мог бы запустить ту программу (LiveEffect).

### Вопрос

Думаю вы поняли суть вопроса, но я его повторю: Как использовать подобный код в своих приложениях? Просто я даже всю ту структуру не понимаю. Может подскажите статью/литературу/поделитесь личным опытом?

Comment: Непонятно, что вы пробьовали, ведь на самой [главной странице](https://github.com/google/oboe) есть даже ссылка [на видео](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_duWv9IPNvx9YBudNMmLSa) с пошаговой инструкцией именно для Android.

Comment: Обычно в библиотечных проектах есть документация, инструкции и примеры использования. Почитайте, попытайтесь: https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md. Что касается примера - то у него зависимость локальная и чтобы его просто запустить нужно склонировать весь проект.